# Git credential helper=wincred and osxchain on same machine

Tags: git, macos, github

I have setting up a mac but I pushed some stuff to my github, and got a message about "wincred"
Looking at my git settings, I have:

```
credential.helper=osxkeychain
credential.helper=wincred
```

How could this be? And how can I fix it?
I've been looking for a solution but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you have two different credential helpers enabled in two different files.  To see, run `git config --show-origin -l` and find out where the two are located, and then remove the one that refers to `wincred`.

Note that if you're using Homebrew to install Git, the `osxkeychain` credential manager is set by that package.  This is usually the right choice for macOS.

Comment: how can I delete that credential?

Comment: The Git command I specified lists the file that contains each option.  You would edit that file with a text editor (e.g. vim, nano, emacs) and remove the line that says `helper = wincred` (assuming you are indeed on a Mac).